# Deixar itens ao lado no mobile com bootstrap 4

Tags: css3, twitter-bootstrap

Preciso deixar os seguintes itens um ao lado do outro como é o no desktop.

**Como é no desktop**

[image: Desktop]

**Como esta no mobile**

[image: Mobile]

Preciso que ele tenha o mesmo comportamento no mobile e no desktop para estes itens.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="contato-itens row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">

                            <div class="circulo-itens">
                                <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
                            </div>
                            <p class="mt-2 text-left d-none d-md-block">xxx</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">

                            <div class="circulo-itens">
                                <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
                            </div>
                            <p class="mt-2 text-left d-none d-md-block">xxx</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="circulo-itens">
                                <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
                            </div>
                            <p class="mt-2 text-left d-none d-md-block">xxx</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nesse caso basta vc não declarar o *bracking* *point* do `grid` na classe, por exemplo, não coloque na div `col-md-4`, coloque apenas `col-4`, assim ele sempre ocupara 1/3 da largura, mesmo em telas pequenas como de celulares. [Link da documentação oficial do Grid do BS4 que fala sobre esse tipo de uso](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#setting-one-column-width)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" />



  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="contato-itens row">

      <div class="col-4">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="circulo-itens">
            <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
          </div>
          <p class="mt-2 text-left d-none d-md-block">xxx</p>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="circulo-itens">
            <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
          </div>
          <p class="mt-2 text-left d-none d-md-block">xxx</p>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="circulo-itens">
            <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
          </div>
          <p class="mt-2 text-left d-none d-md-block">xxx</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Isso mesmo valeu.